# Ajax request succed but I dont get anything from database?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I need to retrive data from database with ajax. The ajax request is successeful but i dont get any data from database.
JS

```
jQuery("#loadF").change(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'action' : 'my_load_filter',
                'name' : 'ada',
                'value' : $( '#loadF option:selected' ).val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Success!');
            }
         });
});
```

PHP- where I call callback

```
//Load data
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_load_filter', 'my_action_load_filter_callback' );
        function my_action_load_filter_callback()
        {
            global $wpdb;
            $filterValue=$_POST['value'];

            $loadFilter = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT something FROM tabel WHERE name= %s",$filterValue ));

            foreach ($loadFilter as $loadFilter_preference)
            {
                echo $loadFilter_preference;
            }
            die();
        }
```

It doesnt work, does anyone have idea what could be wrong in my code?

I am looged in WP, and there are no spelling mistake with DB.

**EDIT**

I found the mistake, but I cant fix it:

> if the Ajax request fails in wp-admin/admin-ajax.php, the response
>   will be -1 or 0, depending on the reason for the failure.
>   Additionally, if the request succeeds, but the Ajax action does not
>   match a WordPress hook defined with add_action('wp_ajax_(action)',
>   ...) or add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)', ...), then
>   admin-ajax.php will respond 0

if you need more info please ask me!

Comment: Are you getting the `success` alert?

Comment: Does just running the SELECT statement in phpMyAdmin (or similar) return anything? What happens if you var_dump($loadFilter);  after it's assigned?

Comment: Yes, i get success alert, and the response is 0.

Comment: I tried also another statement, and I dont get anything ! and it doesnt show me anything wit var_dump. I would like to get the response in different element so I can see what it returns from var_dump, but I dont know how can I do it. I am new to ajax. But first I would like to get anything from database so I can continue further.

Comment: How are you determining what the response is?

Comment: Inspect element /network/  when I make ajax request , you can see there the request and response

Comment: Are you logged in wordpress? `wp_ajax_` action just work for legged in users, you could add two actions, in case both logged in and logged out users can make the request `wp_ajax_nopriv_`. `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_load_filter', 'my_action_load_filter_callback' );`

Comment: Yes I am logged in WP. I am using only wp_ajax_, i dont need ít for logged out users.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting anything back from the database, $loadFilter will be an object (according to https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Row).

You'll need to output the actual properties from the object that you need. Or, just use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), and do away with the foreach() loop.

```
function my_action_load_filter_callback()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $filterValue=$_POST['value'];

    $loadFilter = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT something FROM tabel WHERE name= %s",$filterValue ));

    echo json_encode($loadFilter);
}
```

**Edit...**

Just saw that you're not getting anything back from the DB. Don't worry about the AJAX part yet then - you need to work out why your DB is returning nothing. Are there any rows in the table you're selecting from? Are the table and column names all spelled correctly?

To help answer these questions, make sure PHP errors are all turned on.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1); 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I am still getting nothing from DB, I have double checked columns name, and I have only two columns, with name and something.